# How to convert a C++ macro to a more elegant solution

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I wrote a C++ macro to wrap the execution of two generic functions:

```
#define DO_ACTIONS( action1, action2, handle ) \
    ResetEvent( handle );                      \
    action1                                    \
    action2                                    \
    // other common stuff...
```

Usage examples:

```
DO_ACTIONS( function1( 1, 2, 3 );,
            function2();,
            m_handleEvent );

DO_ACTIONS( function1( "some text" );,
            function2( -3 );,
            m_handleEvent );
```

I would like to replace this code with something more elegant.  Do you think templates can help me with that? Any other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: In C++11 I would simply delete the macro.  Come to think of it, I don't know that action requires anything C++11 specific.

Comment: If this is the actual code: just remove the macro outright. It has no added value. @CrazyEddie: GMTA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinary templates should suffice for the facility, since there's nothing variadic about your problem:

```
template <typename F1, typename F2>
void do_actions(F1 f1, F2 f2, handle_type handle)
{
    ResetEvent(handle);
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

At the call site you could use lambda expressions to generate callable objects:

```
do_actions([](){ function1(1, 2,3 ); },
           [](){ function2(); },
           m_handleEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at std::bind to fix those arguments at setup time.